# Modifying readthedown markdown

Tags: css, r-markdown

I am trying to change the background color of the header panel in readthedown RMD format.

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: rmdformats::readthedown
css: Style.css
---
```

My style CSS is with changed colors to #008B8B

```
#main .nav-pills > li.active > a,
#main .nav-pills > li.active > a:hover,
#main .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
   background-color: #22983B;
}

#main .nav-pills > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #008B8B;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,legend{
    color: #008B8B;
}

#nav-top span.glyphicon {
  color: #008B8B;
}

#table-of-contents header{
    color:#008B8B;
    background-color: #008B8B;
}

#table-of-contents h2{
    background-color:#22983B;
}



a:hover{
    color:#008B8B
}

a:visited{
    color:#008B8B
}
```

But i am still getting :

[image]

I would like to change :
background color of the toc left , background color of TOC header ( right now in red ) and hover color of the Title 1 and 2. What are the tags for those in the CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change text and background colours of the active toc sections and hover toc items you'll want the `sidebar a`,  try the following

```
#sidebar {
    color: #D9AB16;
    background: #113458;
}

#sidebar h2 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #4096B8;
}

#sidebar a {
    color: #3F4548;
}

#sidebar a:hover {
    background-color: #3F4548;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was only able to get the sidebar and the sidebar header for now, and that was

```
#sidebar {
  background-color: #008B8B;
}

#sidebar h2 {
  background-color: #008B8B;
}
```